# Parse file and delete bracket content using Java

Tags: java, regex, parsing

I have a configuration file which has multiple records respecting the syntax below :

```
# some comment
Job {
   Name = "Job1"
   Include {
      Where = /etc
   }
}
```

I'm writing a Java program to parse this file, if user chooses to delete "Job1", then the program will delete the entire bracket of "Job1".

The hard part is how to find bracket that matches the first open one, as shows there are several brackets inside the first one. And sometimes we have records not respecting 100% the syntax like :

```
# some comment
Job   {
   Include {
      Where = /etc
   }
   Name = "Job1"
}
```

So it makes the parsing even harder. Could anyone give me some ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Any chance you can alter the syntax? And e.g. store it as real-and-not-only-looking-like JSON?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that with regular expressions, you need a grammar parser such as [Antlr](http://www.antlr.org).

Comment: Thanks for the link, but it seems a bit too complicated. Now I think perhaps I can find the "Job" bracket first, then parse the content inside. I'm not sure if I can achieve that.